# Asp.Net MVC WebApi CORS Request fails - no proposed solutions affecting the outcome

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, cors, webapi

I have an Asp.Net NVC5 web application (running under Visual Studio 2017) on localhost:59569 (SiteApi).  I have a second website (also running under Visual Studio 2017) on localhost:61527 (SiteClient) where a page once loaded makes the following api call to SiteApi:

```
$http({
    url: 'http://localhost:59569/api/V2/' + alias,
    method: 'POST',
    data: pm,
    xhrFields: { withCredentials: true },
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8' }
    })
    .then(th, ex);
```

NOTE: I have tried this with and without the xhrFields + withCredentials information using Microsoft IE, Microsoft Edge and Chrome.

Back on SiteApi the resulting preflight call for OPTIONS is intercepted by the following code in Global.asax which executes exactly as written and I can trace through the if statement when an inbound call for OPTIONS triggers it.

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest()
{
    if (Request.Headers.AllKeys.Contains("Origin") && Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
    {
        Response.Clear();
        Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept, X-Requested-With, Session");
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
    }
}
```

The intention being to send the desired headers back to the client to allow CORS to function properly - however immediately after this code is executed the web page back on SiteClient reports that the request has been blocked due to missing 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is missing and I can see that none of the headers I have specified have made it back to the client.

In an attempt to have CORS work I have the following nuget packages installed on the SiteAPI project.

- Microsoft.AspNet.Cors
- Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors

I adjusted the WebApiConfig.Register() method to include:

```
   // Web API configuration and services
   config.EnableCors();
```

I have tried many variations of adding the filter attributes to my controller like so:

```
[EnableCors("*", "*", "*", SupportsCredentials = true)]
```

I have tried adding my own custom ActionFilterAttribute from solutions found in other CORS related questions on stackoverflow - for example (among various others):

```
    public override void OnActionExecuting(System.Web.Mvc.ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
```

I have the following to my web.config file:

```
<handlers>
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
  <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
  <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
</handlers>
```

I have ALL these solutions live in my project and in spite of this I still get CORS errors on the client side.

So the caveat here is that I also have a custom filter that looks up security on each API call - which works fine with ALL calls made from pages running on SiteApi.  In the case of calls from SiteClient (CORS calls) the security filter never fires at all though I am getting 401 errors reported on the client in addition to the errors due to the missing CORS related headers.

I have cleared the caches of all browsers and the server itself.  This is my first time working with CORS and I'm already exhausted from working with what really should be a simple solution.  Looking for solutions here and would appreciate some help from those in the know.

Request Headers:

```
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 2
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Host: localhost:59569
Origin: http://localhost:61527
Referer: http://localhost:61527/Home/Index
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.106 Safari/537.36 Edg/80.0.361.54
```

Response Headers:

```
Cache-Control: private
Content-Length: 6115
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: Wed, 19 Feb 2020 00:46:06 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate
WWW-Authenticate: NTLM
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?QzpcVXNlcnNcbngyMDA4MjZcRGV2XFRlY2hJVFxFQVNJV2ViQXBwXGFwaVxWMlxHZXRDb21tYW5kcw==?=
```

Comment: What at the exact errors that the browser is logging in the devtools console?

Comment: I'm getting a 200 on the preflight OPTIONS call and a 401 unauthorized on the resulting call for data.I can step through the the preflight call but even with breakpoints set on the code that services the API I cannot see no debug the api call - I just receive a 401 error.

Answer (score 1):

This is the flow I use.  Sometimes browsers don't like "*".  Other times, browsers don't like localhost, either.  This is the logic I use (modify the allow headers as you see fit).  It could be the fact that you aren't allowing the access control headers in your allowed headers, too:

[Add this to Global.asax]

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        var originKey =
            Request.Headers.AllKeys.FirstOrDefault(
                a => a.Equals("origin", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));

        if (originKey != null && Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS"))
        {
// Optional Whitelist check here can return without the headers below to reject CORS
            Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", Request.Headers[originKey]);
            Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
            Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUSH, DELETE, OPTIONS");
            Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
                "Authorization, Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, X-Requested-With, Access-Control-Allow-Method, Accept");

            Response.Flush();
            Response.End();
            return;
        }
}
```

Comment: I used this code to get me over the hump of CORS rejection for now.  The problem is that it allows every origin.  I'm still getting a 401 after the preflight ORIGIN call but the debugger never catches the actual call for data.

Comment: @Andrew This lets all through, but you can easily add a whitelist check (I omitted that since returning "*" is the same thing as just spitting back the Origin that was sent in).  If the orignKey is not a valid Url, you can return 401 directly at this point, too.  As for 401, you aren't sending any Authorization header here, so if you have [Authorized] attribute on your endpoint, it will never go through.

Comment: I have an ActionFilterAttribute on the controller that Implements IAuthenticationFilter and IAuthorizationFilter which I presume was supposed to handle this for me.  I inherited the project and wile this filter works for authorizing non CORS related post it never fires for CORS related post.  I don't see where I could add the header you mentioned in the code that handles the OPTIONS request.

Comment: Hey Andrew.  This goes in the global.asax.  You add this code to protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e) { }

Comment: Daniel, I have your code verbatim in global.asax, can watch it execute in the debugger.  I see the response headers including Access-Control-Allow-Origin with correct origin value. The pre-flight OPTIONS call succeeds, the followup call fails,is still blocked. I cannot intercept the second request no matter where I set a break point - never see it in Visual Studio.

On the browser(s) side the OPTIONS gets a 200 response but the POST a 401 with a message that the call is blocked due to CORS policy. No Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is present on the requested resource.